# Effect of Electric charge on balloon

Tags: electricity

I recently provided a charge to a (inflated) balloon which popped within seconds of introducing the charge ? Why so?

Comment: Accident, bad balloon membrane, spark.  There are too many answers.  Did you repeat the experiment? XKCD describes many of us: https://xkcd.com/242/

Comment: Could be bad balloon membrane because it was cheap . I repeated it with same results

Comment: We routinely place charge on balloons by rubbing the balloons together or rubbing them across a polyester cloth.  If you want like charges on the balloons, be sure to discharge the cloth after each balloon.

Comment: How did you place the charge?  If there are enough positive charges on one object and negative charges on the other, electrons may start to flow through the air gap between them.  This heats the air, which increases the flow of electrons, which creates more heat.  The effect is intensified if charges are concentrated on an edge or a point before they jump the gap between the charged object and the balloon.  The heat can be sufficient to create a spark, and to melt the balloon membrane.